# In a Venn diagram of the scriptures of Islam, Catholicism, and Judaism, what would be, roughly, the percentages of each portion?

Tags: scriptures, comparative-religion

In a Venn diagram of the scriptures of Islam, Catholicism, and Judaism, what would be, roughly, the percentages of each portion? I am wondering how much they overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rough Venn diagram (not to scale):

> [image: Venn diagram of Catholic, Hebrew, and Islamic scriptures]

The approximate numbers of verses in each of these books is as follows:

- Catholic Bible (35,500 verses)

  - Hebrew Tanakh / Old Testament (23,000)

    - Torah (6,000)
    - Psalms (2,500)
  - Deuterocanonical books (4,500)
  - New Testament (8,000)
- Quran (6,000)

Of course, the length of verses varies by book, so it's not a great tool for comparison, but it at least provides a starting point.